# Elasticsearch nested Query parseException

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

I get a parse exception when i want to get data out of my elastic search. My document looks like this

```
{
        "_index": "some name",
        "_type": "row",
        "_id": "665",
        "_score": 6.3700795,
        "_source": {
           "dateOfClaim": 1215986400000,
           "employer": {
              "username": null,
              "password": null,
              "name": "customer",
              "customerNumber": "some number",
              "dosierNumbers": null
           },
           "recipient": {
              "username": null,
              "password": null,
              "name": "some name",
              "taxNumber": "some number"
           },
           "claim": 402401,
           "dosierNumber": "",
           "worthWayTaxes": "",
           "good": {
              "brutoWeight": 25,
              "nettoWeight": 25050,
              "coll": 25000,
              "taxWorth": "58830.67",
              "eori": ""
           },
           "poDValues": "YES",
           "correctedTaxNumber": null,
           "note": null
        }
     },
```

and my query looks like this

```
POST /customs/_search
{
    "nested" : {
        "path" : "employer",
        "score_mode" : "none",
        "query" : {
            "match": {
               "employer.name" : "customer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get all document of a specific employer where the poDValue is NO. But my query already gives me a parseexception (All shards failed for phase: [query]) even without say that the poDValue should be NO.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the concept of nested objects. You are just using an object content, not nested object. Check this one:

```
POST /_search
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
           "employer.titel": {
              "value": "Dit is mijn titel"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought the same but also with the query key it is giving me the same error